# Convert big php project from register_globals to _GET["param"]

Tags: php, php4, register-globals

I have a rather big php site, which was written for php4 and register_globals enabled. It is old custom CMS. Now I want to run it on the php5 hosting without register_globals. Is it possible to change parameters parsing from $id to $_GET["id"] automatically, with some script?

I can get parameters names from `wget -r` on this site.

It have dozens of php scripts, and it is not very easy to do this change manually.

PS: UPDATE: I want to convert only GET variables. The additional line is `$var_name = $_GET["var_name"]` for each parameter. This line should be inserted very high in the script, e.g. by adding a new `<? ?>` section at very top.

Comment: The main issue is what `$id` is: a `$_POST` variable, a `$_GET` variable, a `$_SESSION` variable, ... It's almost impossible to determine by script, and usually requires human intervention.

Comment: sure you can write a script to find all the places with register Globals. but for migrating it is a good idea to change them manually. because the code can be complexe

Comment: Also, if the $id is used in a string ("Hello $id") you would have to replace the string by splitting it up. So yeah, do it manually by finding all $id references and have $_GET["id"] under your paste button, but look if you need to use another type/do more work.

Comment: @mc10 you can use `$_REQUEST` which will access post or get.

Comment: @Jason Using `$_REQUEST` leaves your application open for a `$_GET` request if it expects a `$_POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the actual finding/replacing might take more time, doing this manually will most likely result in less bugs / weird behaviour.

If are not the original author of the application, then this manual finding/replacing is also an opportunity for you to become much more familiar with the codebase than some automatic method.

Automatic: fast, almost definitely will result in some horrible bugs

Manual: slower (likely), almost definitely will result in better understanding, less bugs - and any bugs that are introduced will be easier to fix because of your better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I'm not an author, and I not a php programmer. I want not to be more familiar with this cms. It is an appeal from my friend to move the site from broken server to the shared hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Running such tool would introduce great risk of introducing errors in code.

I'd suggest running extract() on superglobals, so that you force register_globals and aplication will work properly.

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.extract.php

Next, when everything will be ok, write an OO wrapper for input parameters, pack it into nice DI Container and start manually transitioning whole script to the new style.

Comment: I would at least use `extract(array_intersect_key($_POST, ...))` to whitelist the expected variables.

Comment: +1, but we don't know what edge cases may that application suffer from.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tools that help you in the conversion, but you have several options:

1. Simulate register globals by doing the same thing that register_globals did: At the beginning of the script, put all variables from GET and POST into the global variable namespace (i.e. via `extract`). While this is fastest and the most easy solution, it will lead to the security problems that register_globals was known for, and it doesn't help with the performance of your application
2. Determine the variables that are used and load them only via the init script into $GLOBALS only. Still not nice
3. Determine the variables that are used and replace the GLOBALS usage with REQUEST
4. Walk through it manually. This way, you can be sure everything is correct and will have the least trouble afterwards.

From your description, solution 1 or 2 might be the best for you since the cms doesn't seem to be updated anyway (which is a shame).